# WebView and DownloadListener make two GET requests? How to change that behavior?

Tags: java, android, webview, download

I have a `WebView` from which I download with `DownloadListener` and `HttpUrlconnection` works correctly! But I have noticed that when I download the download counter of the file in question it increases by 2 as if two downloads had been made instead of one.

After analyzing a bit I understand that `WebView` does a `GET` to the URL and when it cannot manage the content then `DownloadListener` acts and performs another `GET` to determine the name of the file the extension etc.

Is there any way to approach this in another way and that a single request be sent?